# Not enough resources when executing

Tags: c++, c++14

```
// End Of Line.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
ifstream input_file;
int EOL = 0;
int main()
{
//Enter end of line data into file
input_file.open("EOL Data", ios::in);
do
{
    cout << "\n" << "\n" << "\n" << "\n";
    ++EOL;
} while (EOL == 0);
}

// Run program: Ctrl + F5 or Debug > Start Without Debugging menu
// Debug program: F5 or Debug > Start Debugging menu

// Tips for Getting Started: 
//   1. Use the Solution Explorer window to add/manage files
//   2. Use the Team Explorer window to connect to source control
//   3. Use the Output window to see build output and other messages
//   4. Use the Error List window to view errors
//   5. Go to Project > Add New Item to create new code files, or Project > Add Existing Item to add 
        existing code files to the project
//   6. In the future, to open this project again, go to File > Open > Project and select the .sln 
        file
```

When trying to execute the above, get the error" Not enough resources to execute the program". Not
sure why this error is being posted.

Comment: What's the purpose of this program? From what I can see it will print 4 `\n` (newlines) and exit. [I can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/3GePve) the resource problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, opening the file is input, should have been opened as output. Not sure why this would generate a resource limitation problem.

Comment: As I mentioned before, should have been declared as output_file. Not sure yet why I got a resources error for this declaration. The purpose for the program was to output the "\n" characters so that I could determine the hex value.